# What does the word "health" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am not sure about the meaning of the word "health" in the following sentence:

"This supercar has an impressive  amount of health."

I found the following meanings of the word "health" on the Merriam-Webster's website:

> 1a : the condition of being sound in body, mind, or spirit
>   She is the picture of health.
>   especially : freedom from physical disease or pain
>   nursed them back to health
>   b : the general condition of the body
>   How is your mother's health?
>   in poor health
>   enjoys good health
>   2a : a condition in which someone or something is thriving or doing well : WELL-BEING
>   defending the health of the beloved oceans
>   — Peter Wilkinson
>   b : general condition or state
>   poor economic health
>   3 : a toast to someone's health or prosperity"

None of the above-mentioned meanings fits the given context.

The sentence is part of  a description of a game in which the player has to reach destinations to score points. The supercars can be bought by investing the game currency.

Unfortunately, I cannot share more details due to a confidentiality contract.

Comment: It's pretty much meaningless.  One might derive a meaning if more context were provided, though.

Comment: What's the context for "This supercar has an impressive amount of health."?

Comment: Maybe the author meant to use the word "stealth" (though I doubt it!).

Comment: "The sentence is part of a description of a game." In that case, I assume that every object has a certain amount of "health." Once its health is gone, the object is destroyed. This is common to a lot of games. But this is pure speculation. Unless you can provide more context (which you say you can't), nobody can answer your question. Except for the developers or players of the game.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that, in the game, the car is going to have "health" the same way human video game characters do.  The car will probably only be able to take a specific amount of damage before it's not usable or the player "dies".  It's not so much about the usage of the word with its legitimate definition as it is about the term "health" used in games.